# Unable to post select multiple using jQuery .ajax() to php codeIgniter

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I'm trying to post multiple values of select element to php, which is giving error only in .ajax post. It works fine with HTML form post.

**JS:**

```
function serealizeSelects(select){
      var array = [];
      select.each(function(){ array.push($(this).val()) });
      return array;
    }

$("#go").on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    if($("#title").val()=='') swal('','Please enter the title.','warning');
    else{
        $("#go").text('Publishing...');
        $("#go").prop('disabled',true);
        $.ajax({
          url: '<?=base_url();?>'+'classes/add_notes',
          type: "POST",
          data: {
            title: $("#title").val(),
            content: $("#content").val(),
            file: upFile,
            class: JSON.stringify(serealizeSelects($('.selectpicker'))),
            <?=$this->security->get_csrf_token_name();?>:'<?=$this->security->get_csrf_hash();?>',
          },
          dataType: "json",
          success: function(data){
            $("#go").text('Publish');
            $("#go").prop('disabled',false);
            if(data.error=='false'){
              swal('Published','Your notes has been shared to selected classes.');
            }
            else{
              if(data.error_code=='1') swal('','Please fill fields properly!','warning');
              else if(data.error_code=='2') swal('','Unauthorised','error');
              else swal('','Something went wrong','error');
            }
          },
          error: function(){
            $("#go").text('Publish');
            $("#go").prop('disabled',false);
            swal('','Some error occured','error');
          }
        });
      }
  });
```

**HTML:**

```
<select class="selectpicker" data-live-search="true" id="class" multiple>
       <option value="0">Choose classes...</option>
              <?=$classes;?>
 </select>
```

**PHP (CodeIgniter): **

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('title', 'title', 'trim|required|xss_clean');
       $this->form_validation->set_rules('content', 'content', 'trim|xss_clean');
       $this->form_validation->set_rules('file', 'file', 'trim|xss_clean');
       $this->form_validation->set_rules('class[]', 'class', 'trim|required|xss_clean');

       if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE OR $this->end!='teacher'){
         $response['error']="true";
         $response['error_code']="1";
       }
       else{
          $title=$this->input->post('title');
          $content=$this->input->post('content');
          $file=$this->input->post('file');
          $classes=json_decode($this->input->post('class[]'),true);
            foreach($classes as $class){
               // Some task
            }
      }
```

I've looked for lots of solution, none of which worked.
I tried with *class* also, instead of *class[]*.
Nothing worked!
Posting this executes *error* part of ajax.

Comment: What does error message say in console ?

Comment: No, It just executes error funcn. of ajax

Comment: I debugged in postman, array received at php is null

Answer (score 0):

Do following changes:

```
<select class="selectpicker" data-live-search="true" id="class" multiple>
```

to

```
<select name="selectpicker[]" class="selectpicker" data-live-search="true" id="class" multiple>
```

and get its value like:

```
$this->input->post('selectpicker');
```

**Explanation:** For `multi-select dropdown`, its name must be and array like `selectpicker[]` so that it can hold multiple selected value in it and get its value by using its name in php.

**You can never get a html element value in php using its class directly as you tried** `$this->input->post('class[]'),true);`

Comment: " its name must be an array like `selectpicker[]`" - Then, shouldn't you use `name="selectpicker[]"` instead of `class="selectpicker[]"` ? ;)

Comment: Still same error after changing. Though the php code is working fine with html form post.
Is there any prob. in serialize function of js.

Comment: I debugged the problem.
php is receiving null array after decoding

Comment: What if I encode the select array to base_64 instead of json_encode